# How to set boolean status to an object

Tags: java

I'm doing an assigment which I have to make a program for a Taxi Company. So far what I've written does work. Here it is...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class TaxiCo
{
    private ArrayList<Taxi> taxiCollection;

    public TaxiCo()
    {
        taxiCollection = new ArrayList<>();
    }


    public void addTaxi(Taxi blackCab)
    {
        taxiCollection.add(blackCab); 
    }


    public int getNumberOfTaxis()
    {
        return taxiCollection.size();
    }

    public int getNumberOfTaxis(int area)
    {
        int Taxi= 0;
        for (Taxi blackCab : taxiCollection) {
            if(blackCab.getArea() == (area)) {
                Taxi++;
            }
        }
        return Taxi;
    }

    public void list()
    {
        System.out.println("Taxi Information");
        for(Taxi blackCab : taxiCollection)
        {
            System.out.println(blackCab.getDetails());
        }
        System.out.println();  
    }

    public boolean removeTaxi(int id)
    {
      Iterator<Taxi> it = taxiCollection.iterator();
      while(it.hasNext()) {
          Taxi blackCab = it.next();
          int taxiIdentification = blackCab.getID();
          if(taxiIdentification == id) {
              it.remove();
              return true;
            }
        }
      return false;
    }
```

Now the next task it to create a method which allows me to enter the ID of a taxi and change its status. To either free or used. I presume it'd be something like this, but not sure how to do the boolean. For example if I enter the taxi ID which is already set as free in the list, I can type occupied and this will change the status of the taxi.

```
Iterator<Taxi> it = taxiCollection.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
     Taxi blackCab = it.next();
     int taxiIdentification = blackCab.getID();
     if(taxiIdentification == id) {
     }
}
```

Please can you help me solve this matter.

Comment: What is a 'Taxi' in your case? It should be a class by your design, but in that case how is 'int Taxi= 0;' working for you? Is the code you posted actually working?

Answer (score 2):

- Create an ENUM named status with fields *FREE,OCCUPIED*.
- Add field status to Taxi
- Add this method  to TaxiCo

  ```
  public void changeStatus(int id, Status status){
    for(Taxi taxi : taxiCollection) {
       if(taxi.getID() == id){
         taxi.setStatus(status);
       }
    }
  }
  ```